# Can I modify disable_functions using PHP code, or doing it in a way that doesn't involve modifying php.ini?

Tags: exec, php

I was wondering if there was a method of editing disable_functions (so as to enable the exec() function) by using PHP code, or just in a way that won't involve access to the php.ini file? If so, what would that be?

Comment: You might be able to use [per-directory ini files](http://php.net/configuration.file.per-user), depending on your version of PHP. I don't know if this will allow you to override the `disable_functions()` list though; the googles seem to suggest you can except for `exec()`. (left as comment as I don't know if this will actually help)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I was wondering if there was a method of editing disable_functions (so as to enable the exec() function) by using PHP code,

No, because that would make `disable_functions` completely useless: Its there for security reason, but where is the security, when everybody can change it?

> or just in a way that won't involve access to the php.ini file?

Nope.

> If so, what would that be?

Changing the hoster, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is 
**suphp enabled** or 
**if php is compiled as cgi** &

the hoster has not specifically disabled use of local php.ini file,

then you will be able to override even disable_functions using a local php.ini file

Add a php.ini file with all your requirements on the document root of your website. 
It's recommended that you use the global php.ini used on the same server as a template php.ini file, and then modify the line -

> disable_functions

so that exec is not present.
This will work because as soon as you place a local php.ini on an suphp enabled server, the domain will stop using the global php.ini